# VBA code to autocolour text based on origin

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using this code to autocolour font based on its origin:

```
Sub Auto_Colour_Numbers()
   Dim rng As Range, rErr As Range
   On Error Resume Next
   For Each rng In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
       If rng.HasFormula Then
           Set rErr = Range(Mid(rng.Formula, 2, Len(rng.Formula) - 1))
           If CBool(Err) Then
               rng.Font.ColorIndex = 1 'black
           Else
               rng.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80) 'green
           End If
           Err = 0
       ElseIf CBool(Len(rng.Value)) Then
           rng.Font.ColorIndex = 5 'blue
       Else
           rng.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic 'default
       End If
   Next rng
   Set rErr = Nothing
End Sub
```

Basically it changes the font to blue if it's just a hard-coded number, black if it's a formula and green if it's coming from another worksheet

It works fairly well but there are a couple of problems:

1) If, for example, I have a number in cell A1 and then put the formula "=A1" in cell B1, the macro will turn the font green even though it's not being pulled from a separate worksheet

2) If I have a formula e.g. "=5+5" and then add onto that a cell linked from another sheet so that it become e.g. "=5+5+Sheet2!E8" it will still turn it black when ideally I'd like it to be green. I was thinking an if loop that looks for exclamation points might work for this?

Any help would be much appreciated (please assume no competence or knowledge of VBA in you answers as I am very much new to this!)

Thanks,

Thomas

Comment: If the formula uses another sheet it will contain an `!`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CF is probably the way to go, but if you want a VBA solution try using the sheet change event so the code is run whenever you change a cell. Put the code in the sheet module (right-click the sheet tab, View Code, and paste the code).

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Target
    If rng.HasFormula Then
        If InStr(rng.Formula, "!") Then
            rng.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        Else
            rng.Font.ColorIndex = 1
        End If
    Else
        rng.Font.ColorIndex = 5
    End If
Next rng

End Sub
```

If you don't want it run automatically, just revert to a normal sub.

```
Sub x()

Dim rng As Range

For Each rng In Selection
    If rng.HasFormula Then
        If InStr(rng.Formula, "!") Then
            rng.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        Else
            rng.Font.ColorIndex = 1
        End If
    Else
        If Len(rng) > 0 Then rng.Font.ColorIndex = 5
    End If
Next rng

End Sub
```

A third approach exploiting SpecialCells which minimises the amount of looping required.

```
Sub x()

Dim rng As Range, r1 As Range, r2 As Range

On Error Resume Next
Set r1 = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas), Selection)
Set r2 = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlNumbers), Selection)
On Error GoTo 0

If Not r1 Is Nothing Then
    For Each rng In r1
        If InStr(rng.Formula, "!") Then
            rng.Font.Color = RGB(0, 176, 80)
        Else
            rng.Font.ColorIndex = 1
        End If
    Next rng
End If

If Not r2 Is Nothing Then r2.Font.ColorIndex = 5

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a way of amending this so that it can be done on command? (don't want text cells and year/date/etc. cells to autocolour just my selection

Comment: See the second bit of code, just a normal sub. Not sure if you need anything extra to check whether cells are blank?

Comment: That's fantastic! Really appreciate your help. Can a clause be added to not run on blank cells?

Comment: Perfect, really impressed with this! Thanks again

Comment: My pleasure. I've just added a further option which will be more efficient if you have a lot of cells selected.

Comment: Ok cool just gave it a go and seems to work great. Could special cells be used to stop it colouring text blue? Don't worry if this is a hassle as I generally avoid selecting cells with text when using this but let me know

Comment: Do you mean you only want numeric cells coloured blue? If so, I've made a small change above which should do the trick.

Comment: You never fail to disappoint! Any way I can recommend / reward you for this?

Comment: Ha, no that's fine thanks, you've accepted the answers which is the main thing. Anyway, your question was a helpful distraction from the work I should be doing.

Comment: Haha ok I'll let you get back to it

Answer (score 2):

Here's a no-VBA solution using conditional formatting.

1. To format the cells with a formula that points to another worksheet, create a format condition with the rule `=IFERROR(FIND("!",FORMULATEXT(A1)),FALSE)` (substituting the start of your actual data range for A1).
2. To format the hardcoded values, create another condition with rule `=ISNA(FORMULATEXT(A1))`.

The result of this is

[image]

where A1 is hardcoded, A2 is `=A1` and A3 is `=Sheet2!A1`.

Comment: Thanks but conditional formatting on large excel books basically kills them in my experience, hence the need for VBA. Also I'd like to choose when it changes and where (not all cells will need autocolouring) and I don't want to create a lot of separate CF rules for every workbook i work on

Comment: For the latter point, you can apply CF to a non-contiguous range without having to duplicate rules.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a version earlier than 2013 here's a solution that doesn't use `FormulaText`:

```
Public Function RefDifSheet(Target As Range) As Boolean

    If Target.HasFormula Then
        RefDifSheet = InStr(Target.Formula, "!") <> 0
    Else
        RefDifSheet = False
    End If

End Function

Public Function IsFormula(Target As Range) As Boolean

    IsFormula = Target.HasFormula

End Function
```

Then add three conditional format rules to your cell:

- First rule:  `=RefDifSheet(A1)`
- Second rule:  `=IsFormula(A1)`
- Third rule:  `=ISNUMBER(A1)`

I'm thinking it's probably also possible using *Macro4* functions and named ranges - haven't looked into that yet. (GET.CELLS - [using-excel-4-macro-functions](https://exceloffthegrid.com/using-excel-4-macro-functions/))